# Android animation with an ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation, android-2.2-froyo

I have a picture frame that should be animated with a picture in it. I will be using an imageView where my background will be the frame and my picture will be a foreground image. I have to show it in a way where a picture frame falls down from the top in to the middle of the screen with a ribbon attached to it on the top of it. After it is dropped in to the center, only the frame with image do the toFro motion while the ribbon stays rigid and does not move. How am I supposed to make such an animation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your Activity class declare these variables

```
private ImageView myFrameAnimation;
private int iFrameCount;
private ImageView myPhotoLayer;
```

Use the onStart or a button click event to start the animation

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Thread thr1 = new Thread(r1);
    thr1.start();
}
```

Then create a new thread to do the animation

```
Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    while (iFrameCount< 747) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                iFrameCount++;
                switch (iFrameCount) {
                    //you can use a separate procedure here to move the ImageView with your picture in time with your animation
                    //the x,y cordinates ‎l depend on your screen/View size measured from top left corner. 
                case 310: animate_object(330,215,310,215,1);
                case 315: animate_object(150,380,150,420,80);
                case 320: animate_object(80,150,80,120,100);
                }

                   //store your animation images in the drawables folder with the name like img1.png, img2.png etc.     
                String image="img" + iFrameCount;
                resID = getResources().getIdentifier(image, "drawable",  getPackageName()); 
                if (resID != 0){

                    //Use these to time how long it takes to update the imageview/ Set your thread.sleep to around this time.
                    //startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();                           
                 myFrameAnimation.setImageResource(resID);
                    //endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    //Log.d("Frame: " +iFrameCount + " setBackground took: " + (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds");

                } else {
                           //we can skip frames if they are duplicates of the frame before to save space and memory and increase speed
                     //Log.d(TAG, "File skipped: " + iFrameCount);
                }
             }
           });
        try {
           Thread.sleep(43); //43 is milliseconds to give around 23 frames per second speed will depend on your image size that you are animating.
        } catch (InterruptedException iex) {}
      }           
      //Log.d(TAG, "Finished all frames");
      finish();
   }
};
```

And finally have a procedure to animate the photo along with your picture frame

```
public void animate_object(int startx, int starty, int endx, int endy, int duration)
{
//photoLayer is the Id of your imageView holding the photo. You would need to have previously loaded your photo into the imageview using
//something like this myPhotoLayer.setImageResource(resID); before the animation is started.

    myPhotoLayer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photoLayer); 
    TranslateAnimation move = new TranslateAnimation(startx, endx, starty, endy);
    move.setDuration(duration);
    move.setFillAfter(true);
    myPhotoLayer.startAnimation(move);
}
```

Comment: I edited some existing code that I use so hope I got all the brackets in the right place for you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to draw it like a cartoon. Try videoing it first to get the movement you need then create a PNG sequence (using Adobe After Effects) take the frames you want as a guide and then redraw them in Illustrator or Photoshop.

Then create an animation using animation.drawable to display the frames as long as it you don't have too many frames.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to integrate a picture at runtime i.e. taking photo from either gallery or camera and then adding it to an animation. So this might not work for me.

Comment: Hi Brat, Do you want to choose or take the photo then have it appear on screen already in the picture frame? 

If this is the case you would create the animation as I mentioned above. Film it first to get the movement. Then draw it in an animation program (like Flash or After Effects). Create  a sequence of PNG images of your frame (like a cartoon). Make the size as small as you can (not full screen). then...

Comment: Either use animation.drawable (if it is small enough) or do a loop switching the PNG one at a time (that's what I do) and then have your picture animate in a different Imageview on top of the picture frame animation layer and then move the top imageview in sequence frame by frame to stay inside the frame as it come down and swings. That should do it.